# String format parameter is not working in string.xml on android

Tags: java, android, xml, string, string-formatting

in my code i'm sending string parameter to the string.xml using this

```
String.format(getString(R.string.notification_devil_expire_coupon_for_one_user), "iphone", String.valueOf(loggedInUser.getExpiryReminder()));
```

in string.xml im using this to get the parameter

```
 <string name="notification_devil_expire_coupon_for_one_user">Do you even shop, bro? Your <xliff:g id="retailer">%s1</xliff:g> coupon expires in <xliff:g id="endDate">%s2</xliff:g> days.</string>
```

expected output

```
 Do you even shop, bro? Your iphone coupon expires in 3 days.
```

but my output is

```
 Do you even shop, bro? Your iphone1 coupon expires in 32 days.
```

parameter number is added in the string. i dont know where i'm doing wrong in the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the string formatter substitutes `%s`  with values in an ordered list.  There is no need to number them.   So rather than using `%s1` and `%s2`  just use `%s` in each place like this

```
<string name="notification_devil_expire_coupon_for_one_user">Do you even shop, bro? Your <xliff:g id="retailer">%s</xliff:g> coupon expires in <xliff:g id="endDate">%s</xliff:g> days.</string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Numbering your arguments is good practice since the order may change depending on language. Where just one argument is %s, several will be %1$s, %2$s etc.